# Using bootstrap v5 modules imported to Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, npm, webpack, bootstrap-5

I am working on a project using npm, webpack and vanilla JS and I am trying out Bootstrap v5 alpha.

I have installed Bootstrap v5 properly through npm using: `npm install bootstrap@next`

I am importing the bootstrap object as such: `import bootstrap from 'bootstrap';`

Everything is set up according to documentation, but for example when trying to use bootstrap modules in my JS code for triggering a tooltip/popover during a EventListenner as such:

```
var tooltipElement = event.target.closest('.task');
var tooltip = new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipElement);
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: bootstrap__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.default is undefined
```

and on the devTools the call appears like this:

```
var tooltip = new bootstrap__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["default"].Tooltip(tooltipElement);
```

I have looked at the documentation all over again and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, bootstrap appears to be properly installed and imported but it will always throw that error when using its JS calls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I have found the solution to my problem in case anyone faces the same issue:

Apparently because bootstrap doesn't have a export default or it's not correctly configured you need to import like this `import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';` for it to work. And to be able to use the bootstrap object

I don't know why the official documentation says you should do `import bootstrap from 'bootstrap';` but there you go